# Combining None and lists in one line

Tags: python

Suppose we have variables, `num` and `let`, that may be (possibly nested) `list`, `tuple`, or `None`. The combination is to be such that:

1. Neither `== None` -> `num + let`
2. `num == None` -> `let`
3. `let == None` -> `num`
4. Both `== None` -> `None`
5. Return type is `list` or `None`
6. 1-5 should hold for any number of variables, including one, and >2
7. Be a one-liner (one statement)

My approach, with test:

```py
def join(_vars):
    return [x for v in _vars if v for x in v] or None

num = ((1, 2), None, [1, (2, 3)], None)
let = (('a', 'b'), ['a', ('b', 'c')], None, None)
vars_all = (let, num)

for i, _vars in enumerate(zip(*vars_all)):
    print(f"Case {i + 1}:", join(_vars))
```

```
Case 1: ['a', 'b', 1, 2]
Case 2: ['a', ('b', 'c')]
Case 3: [1, (2, 3)]
Case 4: None
```

Any better way to accomplish this? E.g. shorter, or more readable, or more intuitive than nested comprehensions.

(For readability I'd opt for less abstract naming: `[x for var in _vars if bool(var) for x in var]`. Parentheses should also help, though unsure if can insert without changing results.)

Comment: Your SE handle sounds like a Final Fantasy boss.

Comment: @Reinderien The sage of the six paths, from Naruto. Unfamiliar with FF, but which boss, I wonder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, the nested comprehension is not very intuitive. I had to write it out for understanding.

I am also not sure I understood your requirements correctly. Please correct any wrong assumptions. These are the attempts:

```py
from itertools import chain

def join(vars_):
    filtered = (element for element in vars_ if element)
    return chain.from_iterable(filtered)


num = ((1, 2), None, [1, (2, 3)], None)
let = (('a', 'b'), ['a', ('b', 'c')], None, None)
vars_all = (let, num)

for i, vars_ in enumerate(zip(*vars_all), start=1):
    print(f"Case {i}:", join(vars_))
```

It returns

```py
Case 1: <itertools.chain object at 0x00000221C73F3940>
Case 2: <itertools.chain object at 0x00000221C73F3940>
Case 3: <itertools.chain object at 0x00000221C73F3940>
Case 4: <itertools.chain object at 0x00000221C73F3940>
```

So not what you really asked for. However, the `chain object` behaves like a normal list in most circumstances. It supports the [`Sequence` interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) (but not the `MutableSequence` interface):

```py
from collections.abc import MutableSequence, Sequence
from itertools import chain


def join(vars_):
    filtered = (element for element in vars_ if element)
    return chain.from_iterable(filtered)


num = ((1, 2), None, [1, (2, 3)], None)
let = (("a", "b"), ["a", ("b", "c")], None, None)
vars_all = (let, num)

for i, vars_ in enumerate(zip(*vars_all), start=1):
    print(f"Case {i}:", list(join(vars_)))
    print("\tIs Sequence:", isinstance(vars_, Sequence))
    print("\tIs MutableSequence:", isinstance(vars_, MutableSequence))
    print(
        "\tIs MutableSequence (cast to list):", isinstance(list(vars_), MutableSequence)
    )
```

will print

```py
Case 1: ['a', 'b', 1, 2]
        Is Sequence: True
        Is MutableSequence: False
        Is MutableSequence (cast to list): True
Case 2: ['a', ('b', 'c')]
        Is Sequence: True
        Is MutableSequence: False
        Is MutableSequence (cast to list): True
Case 3: [1, (2, 3)]
        Is Sequence: True
        Is MutableSequence: False
        Is MutableSequence (cast to list): True
Case 4: []
        Is Sequence: True
        Is MutableSequence: False
        Is MutableSequence (cast to list): True
```

So if a caller requires a list, they can cast to that type specifically. It is perhaps more pythonic to not do that in the function already (duck-typing).

Another point to note is that if both elements are `None`, an empty iterable is returned. This will still behave similar to `None` in boolean contexts. It allows for simpler code and maybe more predictable returns. See if that still fulfills your requirements. If not, this final suggestion will fulfill your tests as specified:

```py
from itertools import chain


def join(vars_):
    if not any(vars_):
        return None
    filtered = (element for element in vars_ if element)
    return list(chain.from_iterable(filtered))


num = ((1, 2), None, [1, (2, 3)], None)
let = (("a", "b"), ["a", ("b", "c")], None, None)
vars_all = (let, num)

for i, vars_ in enumerate(zip(*vars_all), start=1):
    print(f"Case {i}:", join(vars_))
```

will return

```py
Case 1: ['a', 'b', 1, 2]
Case 2: ['a', ('b', 'c')]
Case 3: [1, (2, 3)]
Case 4: None
```

for Python 3.8.1.
I hope you agree that this is more readable, intuitive and also debuggable.
The early `return` makes it easier to understand. The additional `itertools` import is very cheap.

Finally, a one-liner version of the above is

```py
def join(vars_):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(elem for elem in vars_ if elem)) or None
```

Lastly, two notes:

1. notice the `start` keyword for `enumerate`
2. leading underscores denote (private) implementation details; use [*trailing* underscores](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) for variable names that otherwise shadow built-ins; better to avoid these all-together, though

Comment: I'll look at your solution more closely a bit later; it looks like you can meet the one-line requirement for the last solution via `list(chain.from_iterable(elem for elem in vars_ if elem)) or None`. Currently my impression is, it's about which Python the user is more comfortable with - a library or a nested comprehension (I for one never used `itertools.chain`). As for the requirement, if two lines offer far superior readability (and spare an import), I'll take it - but the idea is reusability without making it into a function, which treads on "don't repeat yourself" more the longer it is

Comment: For your last point, I argue that even a one-liner is, if repeated at all, not following *DRY*. In that case, I would even suggest a `lambda` if you really want to avoid `def`. But a truly *named* function will do wonders for code readability and maintainability. Also, I think the "beauty" about `chain` is its name... it is a very simple operation, where *chain* says everything the user needs to know. `itertools` is part of the standard library, so in my view can be considered part of the core language (["batteries included"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html#batteries-included)).

Comment: 1. `not any(x not in (None, [], {}) for x in arr)` is an expression that can be repeated, but we don't consider it 'violating' a coding practice since it's sufficiently short - the idea's the same here, to repeat without defining a function. 2. The problem with `chain` is the need to dig up and study its docs if one is unfamiliar with it (as I was), and it adds an import; the core language is much preferred to this end. -- Nonetheless, your approach is a viable alternative to mine - just include the one-liner version somewhere, and I'll accept it.

Comment: The answer is now edited accordingly.